# Updating a file through C++ streams

Tags: c++, file, stream

The following code is my answer to a [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20745184/how-to-update-struct-item-in-binary-files/20794062#20794062):

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cassert>

//  #include <stdint.h>     => DWORD
#ifndef int32_t
#define uint32_t DWORD
#define int32_t int
#endif

struct MapItem
{
    std::string term;
    std::vector<int32_t> pl;

    //  this function also emphasizes the way this objects are serialized to file; if something changes here,
    //    ReadNext & WriteNext must also be updated (unfortunate dependency) 
    size_t SizeWrittenToFile() const 
    {
        return 2*sizeof(uint32_t)+term.length()+pl.size()*sizeof(int32_t);
    }
};

bool ReadNext(std::istream& in, MapItem& item)
{
    size_t size;
    in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&size), sizeof(uint32_t));
    if (!in)
        return false;

    std::istreambuf_iterator<char> itIn(in); 
    std::string& out = item.term;
    out.reserve(size);
    out.clear();    //  this is necessary if the string is not empty
    //  copy_n available in C++11
    for (std::insert_iterator<std::string> itOut(out, out.begin()); in && (out.length() < size); itIn++, itOut++)
        *itOut = *itIn;

    assert(in);
    if (!in)
        return false;

    in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&size), sizeof(uint32_t));
    if (!in)
        return false;

    std::vector<int32_t>& out2 = item.pl;
    out2.resize(size);  //  reserve doesn't work here
    in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&out2[0]), size * sizeof(int32_t));
    assert(in);

    return true;
}

// a "header" should be added to mark complete data (to write "atomically")
bool WriteNext(std::ostream& out, const MapItem& item)
{
    size_t size = item.term.length();
    out.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&size), sizeof(uint32_t));
    if (!out)
        return false;
    out.write(item.term.c_str(), size);
    if (!out)
        return false;

    size = item.pl.size();
    out.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&size), sizeof(uint32_t));
    if (!out)
        return false;
    out.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&item.pl[0]), size * sizeof(int32_t));
    if (!out)
        return false;

    return true;
}

bool UpdateItem(std::ifstream& in, std::ofstream& out, const MapItem& item)
{
    MapItem it;
    bool result;
    for (result = ReadNext(in, it); result && (it.term != item.term); result = ReadNext(in, it))
        if (!WriteNext(out, it))
            return false;
    if (!result)
        return false;

    assert(it.term == item.term);
    if (!WriteNext(out, item))
        return false;

    for (result = ReadNext(in, it); result; result = ReadNext(in, it))
        if (!WriteNext(out, it))
            return false;

    return in.eof();
}

bool UpdateItem(const char* filename, const MapItem& item)
{
    std::ifstream in(filename, std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary);
    assert(in);

    std::string filename2(filename);
    filename2 += ".tmp";
    std::ofstream out(filename2.c_str(), std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::binary);
    assert(out);

    bool result = UpdateItem(in, out, item);
    in.close();
    out.close();

    int err = 0;

    if (result)
    {
        err = remove(filename);
        assert(!err && "remov_140");
        result = !err;
    }
    if (!result)
    {
        err = remove(filename2.c_str());
        assert(!err && "remov_147");
    }
    else
    {
        err = rename(filename2.c_str(), filename);
        assert(!err && "renam_151");
        result = !err;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Beside correctness, I'm concerned with two problems:

1. performance when reading to string in `ReadNext`: "`in && (out.length() < size)`"
   A better implementation would be capable of reading directly a block of data.
2. To update an item a second file is used. Is there a safe solution using only one file?

**EDIT** My interess goes beyond the initial Stack Overflow question as this is a (re)learning exercise of the C++ streams and I'll use it as a sample. 
I also added the code [here](https://github.com/landron/http---codereview.stackexchange.com-questions-38148-), with additional real tests, VS 2008, but it should be easily ported to other platforms.

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to focus on readability rather than performance for this review.
I will also (hopefully) avoid C++11 features since you're using VS2008.

1. Change `<assert.h>` to `<cassert>`.
   Use the C++ headers instead of the C headers.
2. Rename `mapItem` to either `map_item` or `MapItem`.
   The former is favored in Unix/Linux circles while the latter is favored in
   Windows circles.
3. Comment and explain the function `SizeWrittenToFile`.
   Since you didn't explain the binary format, it's not clear why this returns 
   what it does without looking at your `WriteNext` function.
4. Depending on `sizeof (size_t)` can lead to incompatibilities for the binary
   file format if this program is compiled on different machines or even
   just with different build settings.

   For example, let's say I have:

   Machine A -- Assume `sizeof (size_t)` returns 4 (Perhaps a 32-bit machine).
   Machine B -- Assume `sizeof (size_t)` returns 8 (Perhaps a 64-bit machine).

   If I write a binary file on A and copy it over to B, B will not be able to
   correctly read or update the file.

   Having fixed width formats for the size fields would solve this problem.
5. This is subjective, but I think exceptions would make your code a lot cleaner to read than returning error codes.
6. See below.

   > performance when reading to string in `ReadNext`: `in && (out.length() < size)`
   >   A better implementation would be capable of reading directly a block of data.

   I can't think of any standard way of getting around this.
   A non-standard way would be to do:

   ```
   out.resize (size) ;  
   in.read (&out[0], size) ;
   ```

   I don't recommend it, but it should work on many modern compilers.
7. Because this is a binary file format, don't forget to use the 
   `std::ios_base::binary` flag when opening files.

   I noticed you omitted that flag on your tests.
8. See below.

   > To update an item a second file is used. 
   >   Is there a safe solution using only one file?

   I actually like your two-file approach.

   For a one-file approach, you would basically create a `std::vector <mapItem>` 
   and `ReadNext` the entire file into memory. 
   You would then modify whatever you want in memory and write everything back to the file
   afterwards.